# how to shorten this sql statement? (3 subqueries)

Tags: sql

I have problems to shorten this query sql /pdo

What I need is to get different values from different tables from an specific user, for example:

```
User1
Number of posts:23
Number of Comments: 2745
Number of Likes:    654 (given to another posts)
```

This is the query:

```
SELECT 
    p.*,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE id_commenter = :id_session) AS no_comments,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE id_liker = :id_session) AS no_likes,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts WHERE id_poster = :id_session) AS no_topics
FROM
    posts p
WHERE
    p.id_poster = :id_session
```

I was trying something like this, but with no success...

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(p.id_post) no_posts,
    COUNT(c.id_comment) no_comments,
    COUNT(l.id_like) no_likes,    
FROM 
    users u  
LEFT JOIN 
    comments c on c.id_user = u.id_user
LEFT JOIN 
    posts p on p.id_user = u.id_user
LEFT JOIN 
    likes l on l.id_user = p.id_user
WHERE 
    id_user = "1"
```

It doesn't retrieve the values as expected, how can I shorten my first SQL statement? Do I need to use `distinct`?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I am confused.

These two SQL queries are very different. For example, the first SQL query includes the table `posts` but not the table `users` while the second includes `users` but not `posts`.

In the first query, there are two parameters, `:id_poster` and `:id_session`. Do they have different values? The second query only has one parameter, `:id_user`.

Could you provide a little more info, please?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want:

```
SELECT (SELECT count(*) FROM comments WHERE id_commenter = :id_session) as no_comments,
       (SELECT count(*) FROM likes WHERE id_liker = :id_session) as no_likes,
       (SELECT count(*) FROM posts WHERE id_poster = :id_session ) as no_topics
```

There is no reason to have a `SELECT` clause (unless you need `FROM dual` or something similar which some databases require).

Comment: @max . . . Yes, it is fine.  And much more efficient than a `LEFT JOIN` with aggregation.